# Windows 7 edit the boot menu (Remember selection from boot to boot)

Tags: windows-7, boot, editing, bootloader

I've installed a computer with Windows XP and Windows 7 each in a different hard disk.

Boot menu works great, but... is it possible to make boot menu remember the selection from boot to boot?

I mean, if last time I booted XP, next boot XP has to be the default at the menu.

This user won't allow Grub or similar be installed, even Microsoft's boot loader is a nuisance for him.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to Start > Run and type in "msconfig" and go to the "boot" tab you can set which install as default, but I am not aware of any way of doing this apart from a custom GRUB or alternative bootloader. This is what I have on my (single boot) Windows 7 system, although on yours it will have two.

[image]